# apache2.4でPHP動作させる際、PHP-FPMは必須？

Tags: php, centos, apache

**従来の環境**
・CentOS6
・apache2.2
・PHP7.1

---

**試したこと**
・「CentOS Software Collections」経由で「Apache2.4」をインストール

**出来たこと**
・Apache2.4の画面表示
・ドキュメントルートのhtmlファイル内容表示

**出来なかったこと**
・phpソースファイルが表示される
・バーチャルホストが効かない

---

**Q1.**
・apache2.4でPHP動作させる際、PHP-FPMは必須ですか？

**Q2.**
・「CentOS Software Collections」経由でインストールした場合のconfは「/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf」ですか？「/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf」は見に行かない？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[centos](/questions/tagged/centos) は使っていないので一般論ですが

A1.
php-fpm は FastCGI Process Manager なので [php](/questions/tagged/php) を FastCGI で動かす場合に必要です。
`apache httpd` から [php](/questions/tagged/php) を使う場合には２通りあって
- CGI として使う (FastCGI もこっち)
- Module として使う
ウチの部内サーバでは Module にしていますから php-fpm は不要ということになります。
CGI/Module どっちを使うかはサーバ運用者の判断ですね。

`# apachectl -M` と入力するとロード済みモジュールが確認できます。ウチの部内サーバでは `php5_module (shared)` と表示されました (php7 にアップデートしてないのはインターネットにつながってない閉鎖環境における野良ビルドのため）

A2.
デフォルト状態、つまり `# apachectl start` とだけ入力して `apache httpd` を起動するときに使われる conf ファイルは `# apachectl -V` で確認できます。

ウチの部内サーバの httpd 2.4.20 で `# apachectl -V` すると

```
Server Compiled with....
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr/local/apache2"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

なので **デフォルトでは** `/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` が使われます。
デーモンの起動スクリプトで明示してれば当然そっちが使われます。その辺は要確認。

おまけ
`apache httpd` 2.4.x 系列で [php](/questions/tagged/php) を使いたいのであれば `httpd.conf` にて（あるいは `httpd.conf` から `Include` させる追加 `conf` で）

```
LoadModule php5_module  modules/libphp5.so
PHPIniDir conf/extra
<FilesMatch "\.(php|php5|phtml)$">
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

のような記述が必要です。 (php7 なら適宜直してください)

Comment: とりあえず、PHP-FPMは必須ではないことが分かりました(原因切り分けの参考になりました)。回答を読んで新たな疑問が出てきたので、別途質問します

Answer (score 1):

1. Apache上のPHPの動作方式は、回答1で述べられているようにmodとFastCGIがあります。
2. ApacheのMPMがprefork以外の場合は、modでは正常に動きません。
3. Apache2.4からは、デフォルトで使用されるMPMがeventになりました。(※)
4. PHPをFastCGI方式で動かすためには、PHP-FPMが必要になります。
5. Apache2.4からは、MPMの切り替えは設定ファイルの書き換え+Apache再起動で切り替えられます。

(※) Apache2.4のインストール方法によっては、デフォルトがpreforkだったりします。
　CentOS系ならyum経由で入れると、preforkがデフォルトなことが多いです。

動作中のapacheの各種確認方法
apachectl -V | grep MPM
apachectl -V | grep ROOT
apachectl -V | grep conf