# 「CentOS6」と「apache2.4」の組み合わせでPHPソースコードが表示される

Tags: php, centos, apache

**従来の環境**
・CentOS6
・apache2.2
・PHP7.1
・「/etc/httpd/conf.d/php70-php.conf」でPHP指定している

```
$ cd /usr/lib64/httpd/modules
$ ls -la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      55  8月 24 09:02 2017 libphp70.so -> 
/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp7.so

$ cd /opt/remi/php70/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/    
$ ls -la   
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4541392  8月  2 21:13 2017 libphp7.so
```

---

**試していること**
・「CentOS Software Collections」経由で「Apache2.4」をインストール

「/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf」
・modules/libphp7.soで指定しても読み込まれないので、フルパスで指定するもエラー

```
#LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
#LoadModule php7_module /etc/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
LoadModule php7_module /opt/remi/php70/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
PHPIniDir conf/extra
<FilesMatch "\.(php|php7|phtml)$">
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

---

```
# sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd24-httpd start
httpd を起動中: httpd: Syntax error on line 372 of /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/libphp7.so into server:
/etc/httpd/modules/libphp7.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config
```

---

**Q1.**
・httpd.confでのモジュール読込はフルパス指定不可？

**Q2.**
・「undefined symbol: unixd_config」って何ですか？

[関連](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/37428/apache2-4%E3%81%A7php%E5%8B%95%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B%E9%9A%9B-php-fpm%E3%81%AF%E5%BF%85%E9%A0%88)

---

**追記**

「/opt/remi/php70/enable」

```
export PATH=/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/bin:/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/sbin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export MANPATH=/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/share/man:${MANPATH}
```

Comment: メッセージ上は `libphp7.so` が必要としている外部シンボル `unixd_config` が解決されていないのでロードできない、と読めます。バージョンというかパッチレベルというか、の不整合みたいっすね http://mylinux.blog42.fc2.com/blog-entry-653.html 入手された php7 module が apache 2.2.x 系用のものなのでしょう。 2.4.x 系用にコンパイルされた別のモジュールを探してみてください。

Comment: これ以上進めると既存の環境に影響を与えそうなので、一旦諦めることにしました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP は remi-php70 から入れたようですが、
その libphp7.so が参照するライブラリの場所を httpd24 に知らせる必要があります。
/opt/remi/php70/enable 
というファイルがあると思うので、その内容を 
/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/sysconfig/httpd
に書いてから
sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd24-httpd start
を再実行してみてください。

**Edit 1:** unixd_config は suzukis さんがいうように Apache 2.2 のものでした。ですので、そのPHPのビルドでは Apache 2.4 とはうごかせないようです。

Comment: SCLやremiといった非標準リポジトリの事情はよくわからないのですが、Apache2.2/2.4のようなビルド時の依存ライブラリの違いまで吸収してくれる仕掛けがあるのでしょうか。

Comment: @gotoken　試してみましたが状況は変わりませんでした(LoadModuleを記述すると「Cannot load」となり、 LoadModuleを記述しないとApacheは起動するけれどもphpソースコードがそのまま表示)。「/opt/remi/php70/enable 」内容は本文に追記しました

Comment: ビルドされたPHPって、Apacheバージョンに依存しているのですね、初めて知りました…